# Java lookup enum from enum

Tags: java, enums

I have two enums in two different classes (shown below):

```
enum State {
 NOCAR, SOLD, TO_BUY, TOYOTA, HONDA, NISSAN, BMW, MERCEDES, NO_MONEY
}

enum Car {
 TOYOTA, HONDA, NISSAN, BMW, MERCEDES
}
```

as you can see that the `State` enum contains all the possiblities of the `Car` enum.

So I want to do something like this:

```
public void sayHello(Car brand) {
  State s = ... // how to convert the brand parameter into the corresponding State enum?
  ...
  ...
}
```

So I want to be able to convert a given `Car` enum into a `State` enum in minimal code that is easy to understand. I know I can use a switch but that is a lot of code wastage. So please help me here.

Comment: Just for the record: the accepted answer works, but has some drawbacks. I don't mind the accept on it, but please read my comment there, and the content I added to my answer to get a complete picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a `Car` value, you can just use a name-based lookup:

```
public void sayHello(Car brand) {
  State s = State.valueOf(brand.name());
  ...
}
```

As long as all `Car` value names are in the `State` enum, this should always work.

Comment: This for sure works, but it has two disadvantages: as you said yourself : it forces you to **manually** keep the two enums to be in sync. If you add a new Car, but forget about the State, this code throws at runtime. This approach kills compile time checking. You could as well resort to flat strings then! Plus: this solution further manifests the underlying *bad design*. It makes things worse, and over time, more bad Band aids will come in.

Comment: So the *minimum* that you should do here is to have a unit test in the State class that iterates all Car instances and ensures the mapping to State works. Otherwise one typo is enough to crash your code later!

Comment: @GhostCat That's right. This is a `String` to `enum` conversion solution. Of course, I counted on the OP's assumption that "the State enum contains all the possiblities of the Car enum" and can only suppose this is tested. I see the point you're making. But we all know that there are cases where the kind of coupling you're suggesting is a bad idea (or plain infeasible). Not saying your solution is wrong, but that it has its place, just as the OP's original design has its place too.

Comment: As I told the op: just wanted to make him aware of these things. I don't care where accepts go, as long as they go somewhere reasonable :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can give the State enum a private field of type Car. Next, you add a private constructor that takes a Car object, and stores that in said field. Then you can declare your State constants like

```
SOLD(null), BMW(Car.BMW),...
```

But: conceptually, this doesn't make sense. A Car is a Car, and maybe a transaction has two properties state and car (when the state is SOLD), but the state should not reflect a car type. Meaning: whatever you do to get a Car enum from a State instance, your real problem is your design. You are duplicating things by having the "same" constants in two places already.

Your question asks how to best deal with a symptom of bad design, and the real answer is: you don't. You fix the design instead of duct taping the implementation.

Comment: Thanks GhostCat. Your solution is a valid one too and your comments above do make sense and I am aware of the potential disadvantages of @ernest_k's solution but that solution suits better what I was looking for.